# <merge/> in custom View xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following custom view which is based on `RelativeLayout`:

```
public class LearningModeRadioButton extends
                                        RelativeLayout
                                     implements
                                        Checkable,
                                        View.OnClickListener {

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rb_learning_mode, this, true);
    }
}
```

`R.layout.rb_learning_mode` contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb"
            android:button="@drawable/sel_rb_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mode_title"
            style="@style/text_regular"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            style="@style/text_small"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_mode_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_mode_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</merge>
```

It sort of works, but layout parameters (`layout_xxx`) are ignored. I could use another `<RelativeLayout/>` as root element of the layout but I want to avoid having extra level in view hierarchy.

So the question is: **How do I make layout attributes inside `<merge/>` work?**

Comment: Did you find something ? I'm having the exact same problem. It works in the end but looks ugly in editors...

Comment: @Redwarp nope, I just ended up using extra `RelativeLayout` :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For anyone that might still be struggling with this, you should specify the `parentTag` attribute inside the merge tag. You will also need to specify `layout_height` and `layout_width` to make it work.

```xml
    <merge
        tools:parentTag="android.widget.RelativeLayout"
        tools:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    // Child Views
    </merge>
```

The editor should display everything properly now.

Answer (score 3):

Merge useful for LinearLayout and FrameLayout its not suitable for RelativeLayout.

Obviously, using  works in this case because the parent of an activity's content view is always a FrameLayout. You could not apply this trick if your layout was using a LinearLayout as its root tag for instance. The  can be useful in other situations though.

[check this:](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html)