# Android CustomView from xml has a extra nesting ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, nested, android-custom-view

A simple CustomViewGroup is like this:

```kotlin
// kotlin
class MyLayout : ConstraintLayout {
    init{
        inflate(... R.layout.my_layout ...)
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- my_layout.xml -->
<ConstraintLayout ...>
  <TextView .../>
  <Button .../>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

BUT, this is a problem. The layout levels is like this:

```
ConstraintLayout
    ConstraintLayout
        TextView
        Button
```

There is an *extra* nesting `ConstraintLayout`.

Is there any way to remove nested layouts?

There are some **bad** solutions：

(1) Using <merge/>

Change xml like this:

```xml
<!-- my_layout.xml -->
<merge ...>
  <TextView .../>
  <Button .../>
</merge>
```

But the problem is it is inconvenient to make subsequent modifications to the xml.

(2) Change xml root to MyLayout.

```xml
<!-- my_layout.xml -->
<MyLayout ...>
  <TextView .../>
  <Button .../>
</MyLayout>
```

But the problem is you can only call MyLayout from `LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout)`.

You can't call MyLayout like `new MyLayout(...)` (for java) or `<MyLayout .../>` (for xml).

And it violates the principle of decoupling.

So, what is the best solution to remove extra nesting ViewGroup?

help~~~~~ :)

**References**

- [The beauty of Custom Views in Android and How to do it!](https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/the-beauty-of-custom-views-and-how-to-do-it-79c7d78e2088)

**Update**

Fixed - just like this:

```xml
    <merge
        tools:parentTag="android.widget.RelativeLayout"
        tools:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... />
```

See:

- [<merge/> in custom View xml layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813217/merge-in-custom-view-xml-layout)

Comment: Yes,In my way I add a container.xml for merge.xml, and then use tools:showIn="@layout/container". It's shown fine in IDE, but It is hardly to modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - just like this:

```xml
    <merge tools:parentTag="android.widget.RelativeLayout"
        ...>
        <TextView .../>
        <Button .../>
    </merge>
```